# Validate page number when using Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rails-routing, kaminari

I am using Kaminari to handle pagination. I recently found out that a lot of bogus request is requesting an invalid page number, such as `/post/page/undefined`. Since I am using Solr, bad page number got passed into it and cause 500 error.

I want to be able to validate the page number, before it gets passed to the controller. So invalid page number will cause routing error instead.

I have asked the creator of Kaminari, and [he gave a temporary solution](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/295#issuecomment-9139568). However I am wondering if there are cleaner ways to do this. I also don't want to include this logic in every paginable resource, as that will be not DRY at all.

My route example:

```
resources :transactions do
  get 'page/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good solution is to simply remove or correct any invalid or frivolous page parameters and redirect to the corrected URL, like so:

```
# This goes in your relevant controller(s)
before_filter :correct_page_parameters!

# This goes in your application controller
def correct_page_parameters!
  supplied_parameters = params[:page]
  if supplied_parameters        
    proper_parameters = supplied_parameters.to_i

    if proper_parameters < 2
      params.delete(:page)
      redirect_to params
    elsif supplied_parameters != proper_parameters.to_s
      redirect_to params.merge(:only_path => true, :page => proper_parameters)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by amatsuda in the link you provided, use constraints.

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904029/how-to-detect-an-integer-in-rails-3-routes) (similar to yours)...

I recommend adopting the more RESTful routes, described by

```
resources :posts # or :transactions
```

Then requests to `/post/page/blah` will 404 (as they should), while `GET` requests to `/posts` will behave as defined in your application.

Comment: Well, is there a prettier way to use constraint than his solution? And how can I default to page 1 in a DRY way across controllers?

Comment: I'd recommend taking page out of the url and putting it in the query string... that way it's optional... in your controller you could call for `params[:page] || 1`

Comment: I want to use action caching so I used the url approach. Your defaulting to 1 won't work if request is `page=undefined`

Comment: sorry, why does sending params in the query string prevent using action caching?

Comment: [Rails does not make any distinction between query string parameters and POST parameters, and both are available in the params hash in your controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

Comment: Ok it only affects page caching: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#highlighter_627788 but it is prettier

Answer (score -1):

You could validate page in routes like that:

```
resources :transactions do
  get 'page/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :page => /\d/
end
```